# ViewModel binds not updating UI

Tags: c#, mvvm

my issue is I don't update the user interface (TextBlock).

In summary:
by executing a method under translation (ImportData, which performs a series of Inserts in an MS SQL DB) the textblock should contain the time as the Insert proceeds in the ImportData method.

For this purpose I have created a Timer that is started before the transaction

This is the code involved.

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumRig}" />
```

I have also used this statement but without success

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumRig, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The property

```
private string _NumRig;
public string NumRig
{
    get { return _NumRig; }
    set
    {
        _NumRig= value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("NumRig");
    }
}
```

The declaration of the **Timer** and the transaction that calls **ImportData**

```
  {
    Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 500);
     using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope ts = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)))
     {
          importResult = ImportData();
              if (importResult)
                  ts.Complete();
     }
    t.Dispose();
 }
```

and now the **TimerCallback** procedure

**1st version** of the procedure performed by the Timer (and which does not work)

```
 void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    NumRig= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
 }
```

**2nd** version of the procedure performed by the Timer (and which does not work)

```
     void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            NumRig= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        });
 }
```

**3rd** version of the procedure performed by the Timer (and which does not work)

```
     void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            NumRig= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            ONpropertyChanged("NumRig");
        });
 }
```

I'm wondering, why does the TextBlock never update?
What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks to who will answer me
Bye

Comment: Does the code doing the ImportData run on the UI thread? Then you would see the update only it it completed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `TimerCallback` actually runs? And that the property is set on the UI thread? And that the initial value of the property is displayed correctly?

Comment: Yes, the code doing the ImportData run on the UI thread.
I  you confirm that the TimerCallback actually runs.
But there is any solution in this scenario  ?